# Apache Commons Daemon (prunsrv) problems in JDK17

Tags: procrun, apache-commons-daemon, prunsrv

Good morning,

Before JDK17 I had a working setup to use prunsrv in Windows to start a Java app as a service.
Now I tried the same in JDK17 and I got errors. I could make some progress but now I am stuck with the latest error I got:

```
The system cannot find the file specified.
```

I use the latest 64bit Apache Commons Daeamon, my batch file is

```
SET J_HOME=%JAVA_HOME%
SET VERSION=1.2-SNAPSHOT
SET NAME=reaction-worker-executor-daemon
SET mypath=%~dp0
SET BASE_FOLDER=%mypath:~0,-1%
SET LIB_PATH=%BASE_FOLDER%/lib
SET CLASS_PATH=
FOR /R ./lib %%a in (*.jar) DO CALL :AddToPath %%a
SET CLASS_PATH=%CLASS_PATH%%BASE_FOLDER%\conf;%BASE_FOLDER%\security
SET CLASS_PATH=%BASE_FOLDER%\lib\reaction-worker-1.2-SNAPSHOT.jar;%BASE_FOLDER%\lib\reaction-common-1.2-SNAPSHOT.jar
SET CLASS=org.reaction.worker.DaemonLauncer
SET LOG_PATH=%BASE_FOLDER%/logs
SET LOG_OUT=%LOG_PATH%/%NAME%.out
SET LOG_ERROR=%LOG_PATH%/%NAME%.err
SET EXEC=%BASE_FOLDER%/reaction-worker-executor-daemon.exe
SET STARTUP_MODE=manual
IF "%1" == "install" (
    ECHO Installing the %DESC% ...
    %EXEC% install %NAME% --Install=%EXEC% --DisplayName=%NAME% --Jvm=auto --StartMode=jvm --StartClass=%CLASS% --StartMethod=startWindowService --StartParams=executor --StopMode=jvm --StopClass=org.reaction.worker.DaemonLauncer --StopMethod=stopWindowService --StopParams=executor ++Environment="BASE_FOLDER=%BASE_FOLDER%" --JvmOptions="-Dapp.home=%BASE_FOLDER%" ++JvmOptions="--add-opens java.base/java.lang=ALL-UNNAMED" --LogPrefix=%NAME% --LogPath="%LOG_PATH%" --StdError="%LOG_ERROR%" --StdOutput="%LOG_OUT%" --JavaHome=%J_HOME% --Startup=%STARTUP_MODE% --LogLevel=Trace
) ELSE IF "%1" == "deinstall" (
    ECHO Deinstalling the %DESC% ...
    %EXEC% delete %NAME%
) ELSE IF "%1" == "start" (
    ECHO Starting the %DESC% ...
    %EXEC% start %NAME%
) ELSE IF "%1" == "stop" (
    ECHO Stopping the %DESC% ...
    %EXEC% stop %NAME%
) ELSE (
    ECHO Usage: reaction_executor.bat {install^|deinstall^|start^|stop}
)
GOTO :EOF

:AddToPath
SET CLASS_PATH=%1;%CLASS_PATH%
GOTO :EOF
```

and the error:

```
[2023-03-20 00:09:12] [debug] ( prunsrv.c:1954:main                       ) [17604] Apache Commons Daemon procrun log initialized.
[2023-03-20 00:09:12] [info]  ( prunsrv.c:1958:main                       ) [17604] Apache Commons Daemon procrun (1.3.0.0 64-bit) started.
[2023-03-20 00:09:12] [info]  ( prunsrv.c:945 :docmdStartService          ) [17604] Starting service 'reaction-worker-executor-daemon'...
[2023-03-20 00:09:12] [warn]  (registry.c:878 :apxGetServiceDescriptionW  ) [17604] Can't read service description because registry key 'S' cannot query value at 'D' (rc = 2)
[2023-03-20 00:09:12] [warn]  ( service.c:159 :apxServiceOpen             ) [17604] Failed to obtain service description for 'r'
[2023-03-20 00:09:12] [debug] ( prunsrv.c:1954:main                       ) [ 6392] Apache Commons Daemon procrun log initialized.
[2023-03-20 00:09:12] [info]  ( prunsrv.c:1958:main                       ) [ 6392] Apache Commons Daemon procrun (1.3.0.0 64-bit) started.
[2023-03-20 00:09:12] [info]  ( prunsrv.c:1868:docmdRunService            ) [ 6392] Running Service 'reaction-worker-executor-daemon'...
[2023-03-20 00:09:12] [debug] ( prunsrv.c:1639:serviceMain                ) [15968] Inside serviceMain()...
[2023-03-20 00:09:12] [debug] ( prunsrv.c:1087:reportServiceStatusE       ) [15968] reportServiceStatusE: dwCurrentState = 2 (SERVICE_START_PENDING), dwWin32ExitCode = 0, dwWaitHint = 3000 milliseconds, dwServiceSpecificExitCode = 0.
[2023-03-20 00:09:12] [info]  ( prunsrv.c:1386:serviceStart               ) [15968] Starting service...
[2023-03-20 00:09:12] [debug] ( prunsrv.c:497 :setInprocEnvironmentOptions) [15968] Checking Java options for environment variable requirements
[2023-03-20 00:09:12] [debug] ( prunsrv.c:501 :setInprocEnvironmentOptions) [15968] Checking environment variable requirements for '-Dapp.home=C:\work\reaction\tmp\reaction-worker-1.2-SNAPSHOT'
[2023-03-20 00:09:12] [debug] ( prunsrv.c:501 :setInprocEnvironmentOptions) [15968] Checking environment variable requirements for '--add-opens java.base/java.lang=ALL-UNNAMED'
[2023-03-20 00:09:12] [debug] ( javajni.c:221 :__apxLoadJvmDll            ) [15968] No explicit RuntimeLib specified. Checking registry. Found ''
[2023-03-20 00:09:12] [debug] ( javajni.c:235 :__apxLoadJvmDll            ) [15968] Invalid RuntimeLib '', Checking registry for JRE home. None found.
[2023-03-20 00:09:12] [debug] ( javajni.c:244 :__apxLoadJvmDll            ) [15968] Using explicitly configured JavaHome 'c:\OpenJDK\jdk-17.0.2'
[2023-03-20 00:09:12] [debug] ( javajni.c:280 :__apxLoadJvmDll            ) [15968] Adding Java bin path to the PATH to fix loading of awt.dll: 'c:\OpenJDK\jdk-17.0.2\bin'
[2023-03-20 00:09:12] [debug] ( javajni.c:286 :__apxLoadJvmDll            ) [15968] Loading JVM DLL 'c:\OpenJDK\jdk-17.0.2\bin\server\jvm.dll'
[2023-03-20 00:09:12] [debug] ( javajni.c:414 :apxCreateJava              ) [15968] Loaded JVM DLL '', home 'c:\OpenJDK\jdk-17.0.2'.
[2023-03-20 00:09:12] [debug] ( javajni.c:419 :apxCreateJava              ) [15968] JNI_GetCreatedJavaVMs...
[2023-03-20 00:09:12] [debug] ( javajni.c:817 :apxJavaInitialize          ) [ 7840] JVM Option[0] -Dapp.home=C:\work\reaction\tmp\reaction-worker-1.2-SNAPSHOT
[2023-03-20 00:09:12] [debug] ( javajni.c:817 :apxJavaInitialize          ) [ 7840] JVM Option[1] --add-opens java.base/java.lang=ALL-UNNAMED
[2023-03-20 00:09:12] [debug] ( javajni.c:817 :apxJavaInitialize          ) [ 7840] JVM Option[2] exit
[2023-03-20 00:09:12] [debug] ( javajni.c:817 :apxJavaInitialize          ) [ 7840] JVM Option[3] abort
[2023-03-20 00:09:12] [error] ( javajni.c:828 :apxJavaInitialize          ) [ 7840] CreateJavaVM Failed with error [-1]
[2023-03-20 00:09:12] [error] ( javajni.c:828 :apxJavaInitialize          ) [ 7840] The system cannot find the file specified.
[2023-03-20 00:09:12] [debug] ( javajni.c:1087:__apxJavaWorkerThread      ) [ 7840] Java worker thread finished : with status = 2
[2023-03-20 00:09:12] [error] ( prunsrv.c:1447:serviceStart               ) [15968] Failed to start Java
[2023-03-20 00:09:12] [error] ( prunsrv.c:1802:serviceMain                ) [15968] ServiceStart returned 4.
[2023-03-20 00:09:12] [debug] ( prunsrv.c:1087:reportServiceStatusE       ) [15968] reportServiceStatusE: dwCurrentState = 1 (SERVICE_STOPPED), dwWin32ExitCode = 1066, dwWaitHint = 0 milliseconds, dwServiceSpecificExitCode = 4.
[2023-03-20 00:09:12] [info]  ( prunsrv.c:1870:docmdRunService            ) [ 6392] Run service finished.
[2023-03-20 00:09:12] [info]  ( prunsrv.c:2042:main                       ) [ 6392] Apache Commons Daemon procrun finished.
[2023-03-20 00:09:13] [debug] ( service.c:573 :apxServiceControl          ) [17604] apxServiceControl(): Sleeping 1000 milliseconds
[2023-03-20 00:09:14] [debug] ( service.c:577 :apxServiceControl          ) [17604] apxServiceControl(): QueryServiceStatus OK
[2023-03-20 00:09:14] [error] ( service.c:586 :apxServiceControl          ) [17604] apxServiceControl(): dwState(4 = SERVICE_RUNNING) != dwCurrentState(1 = SERVICE_STOPPED); dwWin32ExitCode = 1066, dwWaitHint = 0 millseconds, dwServiceSpecificExitCode = 4
[2023-03-20 00:09:14] [error] ( service.c:602 :apxServiceControl          ) [17604] apxServiceControl(): returning FALSE
[2023-03-20 00:09:14] [error] ( prunsrv.c:966 :docmdStartService          ) [17604] Failed to start service 'reaction-worker-executor-daemon'.
[2023-03-20 00:09:14] [info]  ( prunsrv.c:974 :docmdStartService          ) [17604] Finished starting service 'reaction-worker-executor-daemon', returning 0.
[2023-03-20 00:09:14] [error] ( prunsrv.c:2033:main                       ) [17604] Apache Commons Daemon procrun failed with exit value: 5 (failed to start service).
```

I'd appreciate any hint please!

Thanks a lot!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is so frustrating when in the end it turns out that not the computer/Java/Apache Commons Daemon/etc. was at fault but me...

So the problem was that I missed a '=' sign between the **--add-opens** and **java.base/java.lang=ALL-UNNAMED**.
AFter I turned the **--LogJniMessages** on the relevant error message appeared in the log.

Also I had to specifiy the **--Classpath** too explicitly.

Comment: Well you helped me anyways. I was hitting the "Can't read service description because registry key..." messages, but it turns out it was working fine, despite the error messages, but finding this example with JDK 17 was helpful :)